# Django Password Validators: If any three of the validations pass user can go ahead

Tags: python, django, django-validation

I am looking at how can we set the number of validations that must pass to allow the user to set the password.

For example, we have these 5 validtors:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
       'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
    {  'NAME': 'registration.validators.CustomPasswordValidator',}
]
```

We want if the user password passes any of the 3 requirements from them. Users can create an account. Any idea how can we do that in Django?

Comment: The behavior is handled by the [**`validate_password(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password). So, you may need to re-implement the logic as per your requirement and call the newly created function during your password validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the other Validators in a custom validator:

```
# pw.py
class WrapPasswordValidator:
    def __init__(self, validators=None, num=3):
        self.validators = validators or []
        self.num = num

    def validate(self, password, user=None):
        errors, passed = [], 0
        for v in self.validators:
            try:
                v.validate(password, user)
            except ValidationError as e:
                errors.append(e)
            else:
                passed += 1
        if passed < self.num:
            errors.insert(0, ValidationError("Fix at least {} of the following errors:".format(
                self.num-passed)))
            raise ValidationError(errors)

    def get_help_text(self):
        text = ngettext(
            "Password must comply with at least %(num)d rule of:",
            "Password must comply with at least %(num)d rules of:",
            self.num
        ) % {'num': self.num}
        for v in self.validators:
            text += '<br>' + v.get_help_text()
        return mark_safe(text)
```

And use it in your settings:

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "pw.WrapPasswordValidator",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "num": 3,
            "validators": [
                UserAttributeSimilarityValidator(),
                MinimumLengthValidator(),
                CommonPasswordValidator(),
                NumericPasswordValidator(),
            ]
        }
    },
]
```